# Socket transitioned into aborted state

Tags: c#, websocket, httplistener

I am trying  to write "proxy" that will intercept communication on one port in my local environment.
At the moment i am struggling to make it even accept socket connection.

```
class Program
{
    public static WebSocketContext WSContext = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FakeDevice();
    }

    protected async static void FakeDevice()
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:4033/");
        listener.Start();
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        while (listener.IsListening)
        {
            Process(context);
        }
    }

    protected async static void Process(HttpListenerContext context)
    {

        if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            
            if(WSContext == null)
            {
                WSContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(subProtocol: null);
                return;
            }

            WebSocket socket = WSContext.WebSocket;
            try
            {
                byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];
                while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
                    if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveResult.Count), WebSocketMessageType.Text, receiveResult.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception message: {e.Message.ToString()}");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (socket != null)
                {
                    socket.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NotWs");
        }
    }
}
```

Even when i call `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4033")` from browser console i receive exception and connection is changing to aborted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Among other things, you are using `async void`. You then call that `async void Process` in a loop without waiting for completion of each iterations, so they overlap and who knows what happens.

Comment: As Evk said, you should always `await` any and all `async` methods, to be able to do that, your methods need to return a `Task` (`Task<T>` if there is a return value). So, to test it better, make your methods `static async Task` and add `await` to the method calls (FYI newer C#/ .NET version can have [async main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) methods)